# Real Time Counter in C# using Windows Form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How can I do a counter in my `Windows Form` for count row many rows was read ?

When I execute my `Windows Form` this counter are shown just when the application processed every data.

**Sample Code**

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        setMessage(string.Empty, this.lblErro);
    }

   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
   { 
     for (int i = 0; i <= xmlnode.Count - 1; i++)
     {
          int cont = i;                    

          ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ =>
          {
              setMessage(++cont + " of " + xmlnode.Count, this.lblCounter);                        
          });
      }

       void setMessage(string message, Label lbl)
        {
            if (InvokeRequired)
            {
                Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => setMessage(message, lbl)));
            }
            else
            {
                lbl.Text = message;
            }
        }
     }
```

I tryied the code above but without success. Still shown the message when the app processed all the data

Comment: You need to run your loop off the UI thread.

Comment: The code is certainly wrong.  It just doesn't matter, it is all over in less than a blink of an eye.

Comment: @HansPassant this is just a sample, in my loop I have a lot of validations, and a lot of research in my database, that I supress here to make easy to understand.

Comment: In the future, at least post a comment or a fake Thread.Sleep() in your snippet so it is obvious where the delay occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run this loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= xmlnode.Count - 1; i++)
{
    ...
}
```

off of the main UI thread. There are a number of ways to accomplish this, but I prefer the `BackgroundWorker` for whatever reason. You could do it like this:

```
BackgroundWorker _worker = new BackgroundWorker();
```

and then in the `ctor`:

```
_worker.DoWork += (s, e) =>
{
    // place the entire for loop in here
}
```

and now when you're ready to run it then just do this:

```
_worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Comment: Work fine, like the another answer of @StenPetrov. Like you said, are many ways to accomplish this, but could you tell me why do you prefer `BackgroundWorker` ?

Comment: @Lucas_Santos, the `BackgroundWorker` is pretty robust because it support progress reporting that switches threads as well as cancellation. It's also available in earlier frameworks than the `async`/`await` pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the loop inside:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ =>  {
    for (int i = 0; i <= xmlnode.Count - 1; i++)
     {
          int cont = i;   
          setMessage(++cont + " of " + xmlnode.Count, this.lblCounter);                        

     }
 });
```